# Laravel 5.8: How to upload, download, and delete documents thats link to an employee (1-to-many relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, file, attachment

I'm new to Laravel and i'm trying to create a HR system to store employee information. My question is how to create a function that can upload, download, delete documents(pdf, excel, jpg files etc) belongs to specific employee?

I have searched all over the internet but i cant found any complete tutorial about this. Most of the content only teach how to either upload or download, but not the whole set of it.

I found an example from internet and my desired outcomes are as below:

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD93o.png)

Greatly appreciate if someone can help me with this from scratch or any tutorial for this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library such as [laravel-paperclip](https://github.com/czim/laravel-paperclip) to allow you to attach files to models, using a trait.

You could also build your own custom system, but that's beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion on using laravel-paperclip. However, i have created my own custom attach files function in the end.